# What does Guppy's paw do in wrath of the lamb?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac, wrath-of-the-lamb

I got Guppy's Paw and I do not know what it does..

Comment: In the future, https://platinumgod.co.uk/ is a fantastic site for looking up what any item it BoI does, as well as where it can be found and what synergies it has.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can activate it in order to convert one of your red heart containers into three soul hearts. To quote the BoI wiki:

> Upon activation, one of Isaac's heart containers (if any) will be replaced by 3 Soul Hearts. (In Eternal Editon it only gives you 2 soul hearts)
>
> Consuming your final Heart Container will not kill Isaac.
>
> The paw removes full hearts first, leaving you with at least a half normal heart before the rest of your heart containers are used up.
>
> If used with half a normal heart remaining, the player can convert their hearts quickly, effectively tripling their health. This is especially useful against the final bosses. (Mom, Mom's Heart/It Lives!, Satan, Isaac, and ???.)

[[Source]](https://bindingofisaac.fandom.com/wiki/Guppy%27s_Paw)

As one of the Guppy items, it also counts towards the character's transformation into [Guppy](https://bindingofisaac.fandom.com/wiki/Guppy), which is a powerful effect if you can collect three Guppy items in a single run.